# How can I properly implement range.find text partial match search?

Tags: excel, office-js

I am unable to get the Range.find method from office-js to work with a particular column that may or may not have a different word in it. For example I am using the following variations of a column name: "total rent" or "total unit rent".

I am currently configuring the range.find method with the following arguments:

```
range.find("total rent", {
    completeMatch: false,
    matchCase: false,
    searchDirection: "Forward",
  });
```

The expected result is that whenever this search comes across "total unit rent" it should satisfy a partial match and return the range info. However it keeps crashing for me and I am unsure as to how to go about solving this issue. The docs don't give much way as to how flexible this method call is or if this particular scenario is covered for partial matches.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unclarity in the documentation. To be a partial match, the cell value must *begin* with the exact string that is passed as the first parameter. So 'total rent charged' is a partial match of 'total rent'; but 'total unit rent' is not a partial match of 'total rent'. I will get the documentation clarified.

Comment: Thanks I will try to adapt to this then.